# What does it mean for a set to be compact? (intuitively)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

I'm having trouble intuitively understanding what it means for a set to be compact. I know that by definition a set is compact if for every open cover of the set there exists a finite subcover.
But I don't understand how an infinite set can be compact,because how can an infinite set be covered by a finite number of things? And when is an infinite set not compact?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, $\mathbb R$ is infinite and can be covered by just one "thing", namely $\mathbb R$ itself, so you are probably misundestanding something right at the beginning.

Comment: @user2345215 But $\mathbb R$ is not compact

Comment: @Sebastien Quote from the question: "how can an infinite set be covered by a finite number of things"

Comment: @user2345215 He's right, though. The **things** he talks about are finite radius balls, maybe?

Comment: But R is infinite?

Comment: Yes, @YGM. R is infinite

Comment: @all It's absolutely irrelevent whether $\mathbb R$ is compact or not in my comment. I just took the first infinite set I thought of. I don't even assume it has any topology, think I wrote $X$ instead, where $|X|\ge\aleph_0$.

Comment: When I say "things" I mean a finite union of sets (a subcover)

Comment: I understand that R can be covered by R, but that's not what I'm asking

Comment: okay, I misunderstood your intervention @user2345215 (charming nikname btw :p ). It's a good point

Comment: Yeah, I definitely could have written it more clearly. Anyway, @YGM do you understand this very simple example of a compact space? $\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ It's infinite, but compact. The trick is you **need** the openness of the cover, so the set which covers $0$ also covers all but finitely many points of the whole space.

Comment: How can you tell that it's compact just by looking at it?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: @littleO your definition of compact sets seems to be most simple and easy to remember. I am wondering are their other cases also in which we can have compact set? e.g. can an open set be a compact set, similarly for unbounded and the combinations resulting from these possibilities. Thanks in advance

Comment: @FrankMoses The characterization of compactness I gave, which is known as the Heine-Borel theorem, is valid in $\mathbb R^n$ but not in some other settings.  So I suppose that "closed and bounded" is not the true fundamental property we care about, and mathematicians have discovered that the really fundamental property is "every open cover has a finite subcover".  Some generalizations of the Heine-Borel theorem are discussed on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem#Generalizations).

Comment: @littleO actually I am interested in a set which have only bolean values in it i.e. it contain only $1,0$. the cardinality of set is $K>0$. does you definition of "A subset of RnRn is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded." still holds? please comment on it

Comment: @FrankMoses So the set you're considering is a subset of $\mathbb R^n $? In that case, the "closed and bounded" definition can be used. Also, any finite set of points is compact. (To be more careful, maybe I should say that any finite subset of a topological space is compact.)  If your set is finite then it is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take almost your example :
$$U = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N^*} (\frac1n, 1)$$

cover (0,1) and is an "open cover".

Let's take only a finite set of $\{ (\frac1n, 1) | n\in\mathbb N^*\}$, say $\{(\frac 1n,1)| 0< n <100\}$. (100 is purely arbitrary, in order to make things the more concrete that I can).

If you consider: $$U_{100} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{100} (\frac1n, 1),$$ the number $\frac1{101}$ is not in $U_{100}$.

And whatever the number of subsets you're taking, you'll be able to find a number which is not in you subcover (do you want the formal proof of that ?).

---

EDIT (proof of that):

Let $C$ be a finite subset of $E=\{ (\frac1n, 1) | n\in\mathbb N^*\}$ (note that it's possible to have "holes", for example $\{(\frac1{100},1), (\frac12,1)\}$ is a finite subset of $E$).

Let $N$ the greater integer such that $(\frac1{N},1)\in C$ (there is effectively a "greater integer such that" beacause $C$ is finite). The number $\frac1{N+1}$ does not belong to the union of the elements of $C$.

Thus we've proved that whatever the finite subset of E we choose, this subset doesn't cover $(0,1)$.
END OF EDIT

---

For your other question, @user2345215 pointed out that a "thing" can be itself infinite, so there'is no contradiction to be infinite and to be cover by a finite number of things (each thing can be infinite).

Comment: thank you so much!! you have no idea how much this helped

Comment: "And whatever the number of subsets you're taking, you'll be able to find a number which is not in you subcover (do you want the formal proof of that ?)."

Comment: how do you prove that?

Comment: I've edited my answer